# Duplicate SKU in rows: in magento csv import

Tags: php, csv, magento-1.7

When importing products in Magento Admin Panel, it shows the error Duplicate SKU in rows.

Magento csv import:

`Duplicate SKU in rows: 76, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 109, 110, 120, 121, 122, 123, 125, 126, 129, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 167, 169, 171, 172, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 189`

Comment: As posted, this is just a statement. First line in CSV file and a sample of lines 85 through 91 might help see what's attempted to be imported.

Comment: Post the data you are importing...specifically, the rows that contain the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will be due to duplicate values for sku in your importing csv file,